# Kronecker product using sparse matrices / tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am currently trying to perform a kronecker product on a pair of sparse tensors in tensorflow. I have found some code on another thread to perform the kronecker product using normal tensors.

```
def tf_kron(a,b):
    a_shape = [a.shape[0].value,a.shape[1].value]
    b_shape = [b.shape[0].value,b.shape[1].value]
    return tf.reshape(tf.reshape(a,[a_shape[0],1,a_shape[1],1])*tf.reshape(b,[1,b_shape[0],1,b_shape[1]]),[a_shape[0]*b_shape[0],a_shape[1]*b_shape[1]])
```

However this is not the case with sparse tensors. I'm not fully aware of how to reshape sparse tensors.

Comment: It would be helpful to be a bit more specific about your problem... What have you tried so far - or found elsewhere - that didn't help you?

Comment: This is the code I have used on regular tensors.